# Apache nifi use in data science

Tags: data-science, apache-nifi

I'm trying to create a web service dataflow using Apache NiFi. I've setup the request and response http processors however I can't seem to figure out how to update the flowfile from the request processor with data from say... another connection. Can someone please let me know how I can achieve this behaviour?
What is the use of Apache nifi, is it used in data science or it is just tool for working on some kind of data. What exactly Apache nifi does.

Comment: NiFi is more geared towards data engineering & integration - it can be helpful to assist in data science, thought its not really a primary data science tool. It depends what you're trying to do? It sounds like youre trying to do some data enrichment? In which case, NiFi is a good fit. Does this help at all? https://alasdairb.com/2021/05/16/enriching-records-with-lookuprecord-rest-apis-in-nifi/

Answer (score 1):

> What is the use of Apache nifi, is it used in data science or it is just tool for working on some kind of data. What exactly Apache nifi does.

NiFi is a data orchestration and ETL/ELT tool. It's not meant for data science in the sense that data science is primarily about analytics. It's used by data engineers to process data, move data and things like that. These are the tasks that tend to happen prior to data science work.

> I can't seem to figure out how to update the flowfile from the request processor with data from say

Use `InvokeHttp`. You can configure it to "always output response" and then you will have the response to work with. NiFi won't automagically merge the response with the data you send, so you would need to have the REST APIs you wrote send you output that you would find satisfactory on the NiFi side. That's a common use case with REST-based enrichment.